# adding link to stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures

In my stored procedure i want to add a link so when the results of the stored procedure are presented in a reportviewer it will be linkable. I currently have this statement but not sure if it is correct or not regarding the format- any information about having links in stored procedure will be great:

```
'http://localhost/Project/CaseHistory/History?caseId=' + CONVERT(varchar(36), C.CaseId) AS CaseLink
```

sqlserver 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT '<a href="http://localhost/Project/CaseHistory/History?caseId=' + CONVERT(varchar(36), C.CaseId)+ '">Click Me</a>' AS CaseLink
```